# How to force spark to avoid Dataset re-computation?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've a dataset which is loaded from cassandra in spark. After loading this dataset, I will remove some of the items from cassandra, but I want my dataset being as first for the next computation. I've used `persist(DISK_ONLY)` to solve it, but it seems to best effort.
How can I force spark to avoid re-computation?

example:

```
 val dataset:Dataset[Int] = ??? // something from cassandra
 dataset.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY) // it's best effort
 dataset.count // = 2n
 dataset.persist(_ % 2 == 0).remove // remove from cassandra
 data.count // = n => I need orginal dataset here
```

Comment: @mrsrinivas spark cache and persistence is optimization way. There's no guarantee on them.

Comment: I agree, I never mentioned anywhere DAG will skip the that stage from execution. But **RDD will not be recomputed every time when action called if rdd persisted** at any stage.

Answer (score 2):

Spark `cache` is  not intended to be used this way. It is an optimization, and even with the most conservative `StorageLevels` (`DISK_ONLY_2`), data can be lost and recomputed in case of worker failure or decommissioning.

`Checkpoint` to a reliable file system might be a better option, but I suspect there might be some border cases, which can result in the data loss.

Yo ensure correctness **I would strongly recommend at least writing intermediate data to a persistent storage**, like distributed file system, and reading it back:

```
dataset.write.format(...).save("persisted/location")
... // Remove data from the source
spark.read.format(...).load("persisted/location") //reading the same again
```