# Avoid lazy evaluation of code in spark without cache

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I avoid lazy evaluation in spark. I have a data frame which needs to be populated at once, since I need to filter the data on the basis of random number generated for each row of data frame, say if random number generated > 0.5, it will be filtered as dataA and if random number generated < 0.5 it will be filtered as dataB.

```
val randomNumberDF = df.withColumn("num", Math.random())
val dataA = randomNumberDF.filter(col("num") >= 0.5)
val dataB = randomNumberDF.filter(col("num") < 0.5)
```

Since spark is doing lazy eval, while filtering there is no reliable distribution of rows which are being filtered as dataA and dataB(sometimes same row is being present in both dataA and dataB)

How can I avoid this re-computation of "num" column, I have tried using "cache", which worked, but given my data size is going to be big, I am ruling out that solution. 
I have also tried using other actions on the randomNumberDF, like :

```
count
rdd.count
show
first
```

these didn't solve the problem.

Please suggest something different from cache/persist/writing data to HDFS and again reading it as solution.

References I have already checked :

- [How to force spark to avoid Dataset re-computation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810203/how-to-force-spark-to-avoid-dataset-re-computation)
- [How to force Spark to only execute a transformation once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56214599/how-to-force-spark-to-only-execute-a-transformation-once)
- [How to force Spark to evaluate DataFrame operations inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380923/how-to-force-spark-to-evaluate-dataframe-operations-inline)

Comment: What is that `Math.random()`?

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking for is a way to ensure that the same values are in `randomNumberDF.num`, then you can generate random numbers with a seed (using `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand()`):

The below is using 112 as the seed value:

```
val randomNumberDF = df.withColumn("num", rand(112))
val dataA = randomNumberDF.filter(col("num") >= 0.5)
val dataB = randomNumberDF.filter(col("num") < 0.5)
```

That will ensure that the values in `num` are the same across the multiple evaluations of `randomNumberDF`.

Comment: the problem is not with the same value of random number but rather with the re-computation of data

Comment: @NehaKumari if the data frame is not persisted, it will be recomputed (there's no way to have both). My understanding was that you would like to avoid caching, and yet have a distribution that's predictable across the many evaluations. Since you aren't caching, even `df` itself is being recomputed on any action.

Answer (score 1):

besides using `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand` with a given seed, you coud use eager-checkpointing:

```
df.checkpoint(true)
```

This will materialize the dataframe to disk

Comment: with checkpoint as well it is computing again and the materialising of data is not happening. I have added : randomNumberDF.checkpoint(true), is there any other way this is supposed to be used?

Comment: @NehaKumari, did you try this? `randomNumberDF = randomNumberDF.checkpoint(true)`